# prolog coursework - ailog

Tags: prolog, logic

I never used SWI Prolog or AIlog but I assume the syntax is the same (might be wrong).

I am having problem when comparing a number to a stored variable, like: "`is 10 < age_limit?`". As I get an Error: `"Error in built-in predicate 10 < age_limit."`

The code is as follows:

```
...

% data values
age_limit(18).

% 3 AGE CLASSIFICATION 1
patient_child <-
            age = X & X < age_limit.


% 4 AGE CLASSIFICATION 2
patient_adult <-
            age = X & X >= age_limit.


askable age = X.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and cannot find it in the manual.

Please suggest me the proper syntax. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prolog we would write

```
patient_child <-
            age = X, age_limit(Y), X < Y.
```

(since Prolog doesn't have `askable`, I am assuming `age = X` part is right).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have got it working. Similarly to "Alexey Romanov"'s suggestion the code will be:

```
patient_child <- age = X & age_limit(AL) & X < AL.
```